# Browser won't display new html code/links from Netbeans when developing in PHP

Tags: php, firefox, netbeans, safari, mamp

Developing with Netbeans 6.9.1 
Using Firefox/Safari 
Using MAMP Server

When developing a PHP application through Netbeans I find that most of my changes will show up in the browser when I Test Run my code. Little things such as links I do or css changes are lost or are not carried over in the browser test even though I can refer back to the line of code and note that what has been displayed is not my code. I am using Firebug so I can definitely know that links or styles are not being carried over into the test run.

How do I fix the problem to make sure I can accurately test my developments?

Comment: This might be too obvious, but have you cleared your browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157752/thilo), this sounds like a browser caching issue.
I use a Firefox plugin called [Web Devoloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/), this has an option to simply disable/enable your browsers cache in a drop down menu.  It also has many other features that you would find useful too.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have tried both clearing my cache and disabling caching... Neither of which worked :/

Comment: From you description it does sound as if it is a caching issue somewhere.  Does the server you are using have any kind if caching enabled? Are you using Zend_Cache anywhere?  Does this happen on any other browsers?